# Restart=no is not working in systemd for Oneshot type

Tags: systemd, services

I have one service which is `Type=oneshot`. Some services depend on this service using `Wants` and `Require`.

As per the `systemd` man page, `Restart=no` is the default and the service won't be restarted even if the service fails. But in my case, I can see from `journalctl` logs that the service is restarted two times.

So the question is: Why is it restarting even though `Restart=no` is there? I tried adding `Restart=no` explicitly in the service file, but still, it's restarting. I want that my service should be executed only once irrespective of the result be it success or failure.

My Systemd Version is 250: systemd 250 (250.5+)

Comment: Might there be some other service calling said unit? `Restart=` is only intrinsic to the unit itself, not others referring to it.

Comment: Does it have `RemainAfterExit` enabled?

Comment: @muru Yes RemainAfterExit is enabled
RemainAfterExit=yes

Comment: @FelixJN do other services depend on this one having Restart=always will cause any problem.

Comment: Yes, obviously. The other units that have the unit listed under e.g. `Wants=` will start it - and try to do so with every restart. see [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: so even Restart=no will not be of any use as other services will try to restart the service.

is there any way to stop this, I just want my service to run a single time there should not be any Restarts.

Comment: @FelixJN one more thing is this service is used by multiple other services why 2 times restart only then

Also, can you give me documentation where this is mentioned: The other units that have the unit listed under e.g. Wants= will start it

Answer (score 0):

`Restart=` is only a service-internal specification and does not extend to other services calling the unit. From the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#).

> `Restart=`
>
> Configures whether the service shall be restarted when the **service process** exits, is killed, or a timeout is reached. The service process may be the main service process, but it may also be one of the processes specified with `ExecStartPre=`, `ExecStartPost=`, `ExecStop=`, `ExecStopPost=`, or `ExecReload=`. When the death of the process is a result of systemd operation (e.g. service stop or restart), the service will not be restarted. Timeouts include missing the watchdog "keep-alive ping" deadline and a service start, reload, and stop operation timeouts.

Note how the restart only refers to the processes of the unit itself.

While e.g. for `Wants=` ([manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html))

> Units listed in this option will be started if the configuring unit is. However, if the listed units fail to start or cannot be added to the transaction, this has no impact on the validity of the transaction as a whole, and this unit will still be started. This is the recommended way to hook the start-up of one unit to the start-up of another unit.

Note that there is no reference to `Restart=` options in the `[Service]` section of other units.

---

For fully suppressing the service being restartet by other units calling it, there would be two options coming to my mind:

*1. Removing all calls to the unit*

Quite obvious that would mean changing all calling units and remove the `Wants=` and alike references, maybe keeping a call at boot time.

*2. Making the unit succeed even if the process fails*

You may just superseede the process to always succeed:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/path/to/executable || true'
```

Of course you would not know if the executable has failed via a `systemd`-query then.